# Is there a way to create a view selecting the greatest line in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm creating an extremely simple profiling game.

1. The user is asked N questions;
2. Each answer has attached a profile;
3. The profile for which there are the majority of answers is assigned to the user (if two or more profiles are even, I'll select the first).

The DB structure for tables is as follows:

```
play (id, user_id)
profile (id, title, description)
answers(id, question_id, profile_id, text)
play_aswers(id, play_id, answer_id)
play_summary(play_id, tot, profile) -- this is a view
```

The play_summary view aggregates the answers grouping them by the profile_id read from answers.

Is there a way to create a view equivalent to this query in which the line with the greatest 'tot' is selected:

```
SELECT *
FROM
`play`,
`profile`, 
`play_summary` INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `play_id`, max(tot) AS tot
    FROM `play_summary`
    GROUP BY `play_id`
) AS support ON 
    `play_summary`.`play_id` = `support`.`play_id` AND 
    `play_summary`.`tot` = `support`.`tot`
WHERE 
`play`.`id` = `play_summary`.`play_id` AND
`profile`.`id` = `play_summary`.`profile_id`;
```

I'm using mysql, and if i try I get the error "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause".

I'd prefer to use a view to have the complete logic in the DB without using functions or procedures.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The final solution adapted from @strawberry answer below is:

```
( CREATE VIEW play_profile AS )

 SELECT s.*, f.*
   FROM play y
   JOIN play_summary s
     ON s.play_id = y.id 
   JOIN profile f
     ON f.id = s.profile_id
   LEFT
   JOIN play_summary x
     ON x.play_id = s.play_id
    AND x.tot > s.tot
  WHERE x.play_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix implicit (comma-) and explicit JOIN syntax. It's a recipe for confusion, if not disaster.

That said, something like this will work (sign might be back-to-front), but this won't perform as well as your uncorellated subquery...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM play y
  JOIN play_summary s
    ON s.play_id = y.id 
  JOIN profile f
    ON f.id = s.profile_id
  LEFT
  JOIN play_summary x
    ON x.play_id = s.play_id
   AND x.tot < y.tot
 WHERE x.play_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks! If the performance will not be good enough I'll switch back to the query instead of the view.

Comment: As your data set grows, I think it highly likely that your query (properly indexed - and rewritten without the implicit joins) will significantly out perform this view.